# The Recycler View does not see the adapter elements

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an Adapter that I pass to RecyclerView. When trying to change the text in the Recycler view, an error occurs android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xde. After debagging, I saw that an error occurs in the onBindViewHolder method when I change the text. At the same time, the holder object is initialized and access to the input fields is available.  Please help, I'm a beginner. Thanks!

Adapter class

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final ArrayList<Income> incomes;

ListAdapter(ArrayList<Income> incomes) {
    this.incomes = incomes;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Income income = incomes.get(position);
    holder.summaView.setText(income.getSumma());
    holder.typeView.setText(income.getType());
    holder.dataView.setText(income.getData());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return incomes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView typeView, dataView, summaView;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        summaView = view.findViewById(R.id.SumListItem);
        typeView = view.findViewById(R.id.TypeListItem);
        dataView = view.findViewById(R.id.DateListItem);
    }
}
}
```

Initialize recyclerview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_incomes_list, container, false);
    RecyclerView = recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_INC);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(incomes));
    return view;
}
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LPNA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnlb.png)

Answer (score 0):

note that `TextView` have multiple `setText` method implementation, e.g.

- [`setText(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) - may take`String` and will show it
- [`setText(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) - takes an `int` and will treat it like resource id (`strings.xml` pointer)

when you call `setText(someIntValue)` then `TextView` will try to resolve such number as a resources refence, which most probably doesn't exists (thus `Resources$NotFoundException`)

so you have to convert by own your `int` to `String`, by e.g. `""+someIntValue` or `String.valueOf(someIntValue)`

```
String summaAsString = ""+income.getSumma();
holder.summaView.setText(summaAsString);
```

PS. don't EVER post text as screenshot/picture, it's hard to copy it...